# How to refer to a second type parameter <T1> when the other type parameter is <T>

Tags: java, function, generics

I am trying to implement a function with two type parameters `T` and `T1`.

If the type parameter `T` is an instance of the class `Feed`, I want `T1` to be of class `NewFeed`; if `T` is an instance of the class `Reward`, I want `T1` to be of class `NewReward`. So there is some inherent mapping between `T` and `T1` - how can I express this?

```
public <T> void onServerSuccessGenericList(){
    ArrayList<T1> myArray = myFunction();       // this line causes problem
    ArrayList<T> myArray2 = somefunction()      // hence I need T as well
}
```

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
public <T> void onServerSuccessGenericList(Class t1ClsName){
    ArrayList<t1ClsName> myArray = myFunction();

}
```

Comment: You'll have to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: The signature `public <T> void method()` makes no sense at all. You're not using the type parameter.

Comment: Maybe you want two generic types? <T1, T2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a common interface for your `Feed` and `Reward` classes that accepts the corresponding `NewFeed`/`NewReward` class as a type argument:

```
interface NewInterface<T>{}

class Feed implements NewInterface<NewFeed>{}
class NewFeed {}

class Reward implements NewInterface<NewReward>{}
class NewReward {}
```

You can then declare your method like this:

```
public <T extends NewInterface<T1>, T1> void onServerSuccessGenericList(){
    ArrayList<T1> myArray = myFunction();
    ArrayList<T> myArray2 = somefunction();
}
```

Comment: It is pointless to have a generic function with type parameters that are not used in the parameters or return.

Comment: Yes, at the moment it is a bit pointless - but this was not the question of the OP. The point is, that what he asked for can be designed by providing a common super interface with a type parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public <T, T1> void onServerSuccessGenericList(Class<T> tClsName, Class<T1> t1ClsName){
    ArrayList<T1> myArray = myFunction();
    ArrayList<T> myArray2 = somefunction();
}
```

usage will be like this:
`onServerSuccessGenericList(ClsName.class, ClsName1.class);`
as far as `ClsName.class` is an instance of `Class<ClsName>` type

But once again, if you need to work with two different types inside of function with parametrized types , you need define both types as type parameters. And pass both to this function.

Also, you have incorrect method signature. Type of parameters should be defined as generics also.

Comment: I *guess* OP wants to pass `T` as a type parameter and have his function to determine a concrete class (T1) based on T (using the described logic).

Comment: in any case answer is: `ClsName.class is an instance of Class<ClsName> type` and he must operate with this

Comment: In this case he would still not need to use generics and simply take two parameters of type `Class<?>`.